# How to change my code to produce a rectangulear shape of the atomic layer and how to add additional layers?

Tags: fortran

I have been working on my thesis on the topic of the generation of Graphene sheet using Fortran in Linux. I have written the code for the graphene sheet but it is forming in the rhombus shape which I wanted in the rectangle shape. I am attaching the image of the sheet I have developed using the below code.

I would like to modify this code to form into a rectangle and also I want to make the layers of the sheet into 4-5 layers.

[image]

```
program test_graphenecoord

     Implicit none 
     real(kind=8) :: a1(3), a2(3)
     real(kind=8) :: pos1(3), pos2(3)
     real(kind=8) :: pi, a0, c, bohr
     real(kind=8), allocatable :: pos(:,:)
     integer :: natoms, i, ii, j, jj, k, n, m
 
     parameter(a0=2.461d0, bohr=0.52917720d0, c=15.d0)
     n=5
     m=5
     natoms=2*n*m
     allocate(pos(natoms,3))
     pi=2*asin(1.d0)
     a1(1)= a0*cos(pi/6.d0)
     a1(2)= a0*sin(pi/6.d0)
     a1(3)=c
     a2(1)=  a0*cos(pi/6.d0)
     a2(2)=-a0*sin(pi/6.d0)
     a2(3) =c

     pos1(:) =(a1(:)+a2(:))/3.d0
     pos2(:) =2.d0*pos1(:)
     k=0
     do i=1, n
        do j=1, m
        k=k+1
        pos(k,:)= pos1(:)+a1(:)*(i-1)+a2(:)*(j-1)
        pos(k,3)=c
        k=k+1
        pos(k,:)=pos2(:)+a1(:)*(i-1)+a2(:)*(j-1)   
        pos(k,3)=c
        end do
     end do
    if( k /= natoms) then 
    write(*,*) 'something is wrong'
    stop
    end if
   write(17,*) natoms
   write(17,*) 
   do i=1,natoms
   write(17,*) 'C', pos(i,:)
   end do
end program
```

Comment: Yesterday IO saw the same / similar question what happened with it (and its potential useful comments)?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Last time you were given some points/questions/comments, did you address them somehow?

Comment: I don't know. someone has closed it and didn't get any relevant suggestions. so posted new one.

Comment: Deleting a closed question instead of fixing the closed post is NOT the way to go. You can become automatically banned if you do that several times. You should explain what the code does. How does the output of the code relate to the picture? You *really* should read the links I gave you. Do not ignore the comments you are given.

Comment: Yesterday I posted a reference on how to find the relevant lattice vectors. Without those we cannot solve this problem. Until you can tell us what vectors you want instead of the ones you use above it is a scientific/mathematical problem and *not* a programming one. As such this is extremely likely to be closed again. Please update the question appropriately so it is a question about programming, and not one about condensed matter physics.  In fact as currently stated it is probably a better fit for the Matter Modelling site than here.

Comment: @VivekKorada maybe try posting here? (as suggested somewhere else) https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/